# Noetherian Space. Equivalent Conditions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

> A topological space $V$ is said to be *Noetherian* if $V$ satisfies the accending chain condition on open subsets: If $U_{1} \subseteq U_{2} \subseteq ...$ is an increasing chain of open subsets of $V$, then there is an $n$ with $U_{n} = U_{n+r}$ for each $r\geq 0$. Show that the following statements are equivalent:
>
> (a) The space $V$ is Noetherian space.
>
> (b) Any nonempty collection $\lbrace U_{\alpha}\rbrace$ of open subsets of $V$ has a maximal element; that is, there is a $U \in \lbrace U_{\alpha}\rbrace$ not properly contained in any other element of $\lbrace U_{\alpha}\rbrace$.
>
> (c) The space $V$ satisfies the descending chain condition on closed sets: If $C_{1} \supseteq C_{2} \supseteq ...$ is a decreasing chain of closed subsets of $V$, then there is an $n$ with $C_{n} = C_{n+r}$ for each $r \geq1$.

**(a) $\Rightarrow$ (b).** Simply apply Zorn's Lemma to any chain ordered by inclusion. My question is: how can I ensure that it is possible to compare the elements by inclusion?

**(b) $\Rightarrow$ (c).** I don't have any idea.

**(c) $\Rightarrow$ (a).** $A \subset B \Longrightarrow B^{c} \subset A^{c}$ and if $A$ is open, $A^{c}$ is closed. This is enough?

I would like some hints, and corrections.

Comment: To address the first one, Zorn's lemma is applicable to partially ordered sets. For the second, the same trick works as in the third, just look at complements and note that the inclusion swaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ascending open chain and descending closed chain conditions are clearly equivalent:

If we assume the open one, let $F_1 \supseteq F_2 \supseteq F_3 \ldots$ be a descending chain of closed sets in $X$. Then ,as $A \subseteq B$ iff $X \setminus A \supseteq X\setminus B$ for all subsets of $X$, we have that $U_n := X\setminus F_n$ is an ascending chain of open sets of $X$ and so there is some $N$ with $U_n = U_N$ for all $ n \ge N$. So this also means that $F_n = X\setminus U_n = X\setminus U_N = F_N$ for all $n \ge N$.

To go from closed to open, we also take complements. This is a common theme in topology: any definition purely in terms of open sets often has an equivalent formulation in terms of closed sets, purely by applying complements. E.g. for compactness we get the formulation that a family of closed sets with the finite intersection property has non-empty intersection, as a sort of dual to the every open cover has a finite subcover formulation.

The maximal element argument is a bit subtler; it needs a bit more detail, IMHO:

Suppose $X$ is Noetherian, and let $\mathcal{U}$ be any non-empty family of open subsets of $X$.

Then $(\mathcal{U}, \subseteq)$ is a poset (it’s just a subset of the partial order of the power set by inclusion); this is always a partial order (we don’t need it to be a chain). $\mathcal{U}$ has a maximal element iff this poset has a maximal element. 
The existence of a maximal element is guaranteed if we can check Zorn’s condition in this poset: every chain has an upperbound. But this is trivial: by assumption any chain terminates at some finite stage, and this element is then the required upperbound. 
So the lemma of Zorn guarantees the existence of a maximal element and we’re done.

If $X$ obeys the maximality condition, it is Noetherian: if $U_n$ forms a chain of open subsets, this is a family that must have some $U_N$ that is maximal w.r.t inclusion. So for $n \ge N$ we have $U_N \subseteq U_n$ by being a chain, and this inclusion cannot be proper by maximality of $U_N$ so $U_n = U_N$.