# How can I show, using the Hilbert Basis Theorem, that $C^{n}$ is a Noetherian space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry

> **Definition.** Let $C$ be an algebraically closed field containing $k$. If $S$ is a subset of $k[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$, then the zero set of $S$ is
> $$Z(S) = \lbrace (a_{1},...,a_{n}): f(a_{1},...,a_{n}) = 0\;\mathrm{for\,all}\;f \in S\rbrace$$

The sets $\lbrace Z(S):S \subseteq k[x_{1},...,x_{n}] \rbrace$ are closed sets of a topology on $C^{n}$ (*Zariski Topology*).

We know that the Hilbert Basis Theorem implies $k[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$ is a Noetherian ring, so $k[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$ satisfies the accending condition chain.

> **Question.** *How can I show, using the Hilbert Basis Theorem, that $C^{n}$ is a Noetherian space?*

I proved in a previous question that the following statements are equivalent:

> *(i)* The space $V$ is Noetherian space.
>
> *(ii)* Any nonempty collection $\lbrace U_{\alpha}\rbrace$ of open subsets of $V$ has a maximal element; that is, there is a $U \in \lbrace U_{\alpha}\rbrace$ not properly contained in any other element of $\lbrace U_{\alpha}\rbrace$.
>
> *(iii)* The space $V$ satisfies the descending chain condition on closed sets: If $C_{1} \supseteq C_{2} \supseteq ...$ is a decreasing chain of closed subsets of $V$, then there is an $n$ with $C_{n} = C_{n+r}$ for each $r \geq1$.

Also, I proved that:

> If $V$ is a Noetherian topological space, then $V$ can be written as a finite union of closed irreducible subsets.
>
> Strong and Weak Hilbert Nullstellensatz.

I wanted, necessarly, to use the Hilbert Basis Theorem.Can anybody help me with a hint?

Comment: The link to the previous question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2745321/noetherian-space-equivalent-conditions?rq=1). There is a typo in the title, $C^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any subset $W \subset k^n$ we can construct the ideal
$$I(W) = \{f \in k[x_1, \dots, x_n] : f(W) = 0\}$$
of polynomials that vanish on $W$. Observe that $Z(I(Z(S))) = Z(S)$ for all $S$ -- in other words, $Z(I(W)) = W$ for all closed $W$. Given a chain $W_1 \supseteq W_2 \supseteq W_3 \supseteq \dots$ of closed subsets one obtains an increasing chain $I(W_1) \subseteq I(W_2) \subseteq \dots$ of ideals. Now you can use Hilbert's Basis Theorem.

Comment: Nice! A little question, should not it be $W \subset C^{n}$?

Comment: Yes, thank you. May I ask: why are you using two different fields, one for the space and one for the polynomial ring? I have only seen this theory developed in the case $C = k$.

Comment: This is how my book defined